# WordPress - Reduce vertical space between main menu and Slider

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, wordpress-theming, revolution-slider

I have created a wordpress single theme, but I am getting confuse with CSS code, where CSS rules should change the display to make menu and image slider revolution look closer.

I would like to reduce the space between the main navigation menu and my revolution slider

This is my website url: http://www.warungrempong.com/

I am trying to use this CSS code:

```css
.admin-bar .nav-container {
    min-height: 0;
}
```

But it's not working as desired and only work when I am using it on my browser dev tools.
When I try to change in my website, nothing happen.

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Your question has many problems.  First, you have to show us the relevant parts of the code.  Second, **do not** link to your site - once the issue is fixed or your site changes / go down, this question has no value to future visitors.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please go through the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: thanks fyi, i should take the tour first before ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the style.css file of your active child theme (or theme), You should add this:

```css
.nav-container {
    min-height: inherit !important;
}
```

When looking at the generated source code of your home page, it seems that your theme is embedding some CSS rules in the html document, as you have this (on line 41 of that source code):

```html
<style id='ebor-style-inline-css' type='text/css'>
nav .pb80 {
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-top:0px;
}
.pt120 {
    padding-top: 0px;
}
.nav-container { /* ==========================> HERE ONE TIME */
    min-height: 0;
}
.logo { max-height: 300px; }

.nav-container { /* ======================> HERE ANOTHER TIME 
          As this is the last instance, it get the priority on first one! */
    min-height: 491px;
}

.admin-bar .nav-container {
    min-height: 523px;
}

@media all and (max-width: 767px){
    .nav-container {
        min-height: 366px;
    }

    .admin-bar .nav-container {
        min-height: 398px;
    }
}

</style>
```

> So may be **you have add this CCS rules yourself somewhere in your theme** settings. The best thing, should be to remove that 2 repetitive CSS rules, and your issue should get solved without any need…